# Xamarin Forms Cannot Archive APK

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, apk

I was using the target framework (Android 9) until I used a nuget package that required minimum target framework of Android 10, when I changed the target framework I was not able to archive the apk anymore. I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: @Jason I cannot copy the error that is why I used an image

Comment: Does the discussion in [this bug report](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5584) help?  See comment about "edit archive location".

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yup it worked thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to @ToolmakerSteve I fixed it by changing the archive directory by going to:
**tools** >> **options** >> **xamarin** >> **android settings** then changes **Archive location**

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5584

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't updated to AndroidX completely. Please make sure all the dependencies are updated and all support libraries are replaced with AndroidX. There is a complete guide on how to approach the AndroidX migration, it's not just a simple switch in VS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/androidx-migration

ps: even if you cannot copy the error message, it makes sense to spend some time and rewrite it in the text so other people can benefit from this post, otherwise it won't be searchable.